# Call FeatureInstalled method on feature activation and after FeatureActivated

Tags: feature-activation

I like to call `FeatureInstalled` method of feature after the `FeatureActivated` method. How can I call `FeatureActivated` method from `FeatureInstalled`?

I have a module in feature and it will adding the module after the `FeatureActivated` method call. So, I'm facing the issue because I have added pagelayout in my module and on `FeatureActivated` method I'll creating page from page layout but module is no added in site so it will give error for that's why I like to call `FeatureInstalled` and in this method the page is creating from pagelayout.

Comment: How did you deploy the feature ? WSP Install-SPSolution or did you add the feature after it was installed already with Update-SPSolution ?

Comment: Install feature

Comment: Why can't you simply add the module BEFORE activating FeatureActivated ?

Comment: but it should be automatically....I don't want to add module manually

Comment: It can be automatically. It seems to me you're making upgrades to an existing environment. The feature is new, so why can't the module be inside the feature. This way it's always deployed before your code runs.

Comment: Or add it with a different feature and activate that one first, whichever you prefer

Comment: yes, my module is inside the feature and after adding the module I will create page from pagelayout.I don't know why it will not adding module first before to come FeatureActivated method

Comment: It all depends on wether it is a brand new feature (then yes) or an existing one (then no).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15744/discussion-between-sameer-vaghela-and-cameron-verhelst).